# Root with Kingo root; stuck at turn on screen

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, kingo

This morning I root my phone with Kingo Root. This night my phone suddenly turned off and restarted while I was browsing with Chrome. Then it permanently stuck at one of the turn on screen.

I tried factory reset by - Home + Power + Volume Up but my phone has no response. But restart by Home + Power + Volume Down works.

I am using a Samsung A7. Does anyone experience this before? Anyone providing other suggestions?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: _Home + Power + Volume Down works_ what did you get there? still it stuck or works?

Comment: It works. It does restart, but it again stuck at turn on screen after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, your phone is **Soft bricked.**

You can make the phone working by flashing a stock rom to the phone(unrooting).

The process of unrooting is a thing that you should do very very carefully. Once your phone is hard bricked, in no way, you can get back your phone.

Since you didn't explain the scenario completely, I found a procedure to do an Unroot.

This website http://trendblog.net/fix-soft-bricked-android-device-first-aid-guide/ (listed first in google search), describe in detail the process and you can do what they said based on your situation.

#### They are providing solutions for soft-bricked devices in different scenario like if stock rom is available in memory, if not etc. etc.

The full procedure is so long and do it carefully

### Don't forget to take a look at : [XDA Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/usercp.php)

Comment: I tried with the tutorial in this link instead.
http://techalike.com/how-to-fix-bricked-samsung-galaxy-a7
Turns out it works excellently. As you said, it was soft bricked and the terms you suggested find my way out on google.
Thanks for your suggestion =]

Comment: Glad my suggestion helped you mate. Careful for next time. Only a softbrick can be recovered.